# I am trying to prove $1-\sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number.

Tags: irrational-numbers

I tried to prove that $1-\sqrt{2}$ is rational:
$1-\sqrt{2} = p/q$

$(1-\sqrt2)^2 = (p/q)^2$

$1^2 - 2\sqrt2 +2 = p^2/q^2$

$3-2\sqrt2 = p^2/q^2$

$3-p^2/q^2 = 2\sqrt2$

I know that $\sqrt2$ is irrational, but how should I proceed from here?

Comment: You appear to assume that $(a-b)^2=a^2-b^2$ but this is not generally true.

Comment: $(1-\sqrt2)^2\ne-1$.

Comment: You can show this using only the fact that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational and the sum of two rational numbers is rational.

Comment: Hint. If it were rational than $1$ minus it would be rational ... As for your algebra, $(1-a)*2 \ne 1 - a^2$.

Comment: I saw what I've done wrong and change the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(1-\sqrt{2})^{2}\not=1^{2}-2$ as you stated. If there is a rational $p/q$ such that $1-\sqrt{2}=p/q$, then $1-p/q=\sqrt{2}$. Note that $1-p/q=\frac{q-p}{q}$ is rational. But what do you know about $\sqrt{2}$?

Answer (score 0):

Setting $$1-\sqrt{2}=\frac{p}{q}$$ squaring we get
$$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^2-2\frac{p}{q}=1$$
Can you finish?